# Persisting and identifying data in nodejs without a database

Tags: node.js

I am new to node and back end so please excuse me if my question seems dumb.
My use scenario is as follows:
I have a simple UI that will make only one ajax call at a given time. I have a node js backend that will take this call, make a login call to a webservice and use the response data to make another get call. When the call is over I will make a logout call and delete the login response data.
Problem:
The problem is that being single threaded and async and having no database the logout call will invalidated the login data for all the calls coming afterwards or that are in progress. I need a way to persist and encapsulate the data for each call without blocking the IO for each request.

Solution:
The only thing that I thought so far was to save the login data into dynamic created variables (based on the UI caller ID) and delete those vars when the call is over. However this seems like a very error prone solution that might also cause memory leaks.
I do not want to persist the data into a database and could not figure other solution, can you please advise?

Comment: What is the reason not to use database?

Comment: We need something very light and the tech lead was against it.

Comment: Look into ```async``` library and its ```series``` function. [Example here]:https://github.com/caolan/async#quick-examples
 This will call the logout function only after the login function finishes

Comment: Finally went with chaning promises. It works and the project will not scale at a later time so for now its ok. Thanks all